# Javascript Color Fading Delay

Tags: javascript, colors, background, fade, onmouseclick

I am using this Javascript Color Fading Script.

http://www.scriptiny.com/2008/05/javascript-color-fading-script/

I set it to activate through 5 different links to fade the color of a **single** background

For example: http://sandbox.scriptiny.com/fader/fader.html (Div Background Transition)

---

The problem is simple, I need to have a delay for the user in between color fading links.

(Ex. User would have to wait 3 seconds to change color again.)

Here is the Javascript color fade file: http://pastebin.com/pxWphT2h

Any ideas are **GREATLY** appreciated, thanks!

Comment: [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

Comment: Unless you want the color to fade to a different color than it started on, on mouseOut, [consider using CSS3](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/css-fundametals-css-3-transitions/)?

Comment: @Nightfirecat I've already got 5 links to fade the background color to different colors, I just need to add a javascript delay in between so the user has to wait 3 seconds to change to another color.. somewhere in this file: http://pastebin.com/pxWphT2h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a timer in your HTML file to not allow the function of changing color to start.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var isOK = true;
function OK2Go() {
    if (isOK == true) {
        isOK = false;
        setTimeout('isOK = true', 3000);
        return true;
    } else {
       return false;                   
    }
}
</script>
...  

<a href="javascript:if(OK2Go()) {colorFade('testdiv7','background','ffffff','e4cdcd',50,15);}">div one</a>
```

See a sample in http://jsfiddle.net/ZphLx/ that only changes a text.